# Creating VoteUp and VoteDown Buttons with Acts_as_Votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR and I am trying to use the acts_as_votable plugin. I can see that there are methods such as

```
@object.vote :voter => @user, :vote => 'like'
```

But I don't know how to call this method based upon a button click on a view, which is my ultimate goal. The underlying methods exist, I just need to provide an action by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.  You can call the methods in a controller (or model) or you can do it with AJAX right there on the page.  For something like voting, the AJAX method is probably more common, because it doesn't involve reloading the page.

Here's some simple examples of the sort of thing you want to do:
http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/19/unobtrusive-ajax-with-rails-31/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264453/is-it-possible-to-call-a-rails-helper-method-from-within-javascript

Also, take a look at the `button_to` docs:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to